# Is it safe to significantly upscale the image?

Tags: html, css, image

So say I have 600x600px original jpg image.

But on a page it's displayed **significantly** upscaled (for example to 25000x25000px), something like:

```html
<img src="image-600.jpg" style="width:25000px; height:25000px" />
```

It also may be slightly scaled further via `transform:scale` animation, for example:

```html
<img src="image-600.jpg" style="width:25000px; height:25000px; transform: scale(1.2);" />
```

I don't want to explain why do I do this, as it's not really relevant, but tldr it's served as a placeholder for a tile-based viewer (before tiles are loaded).

My question is, is this a performance concern or no? Can modern browsers safely display/render upscaled image? Or will there be memory problems or something like that (especially on mobile)?

Thank you.

Comment: Depends on the browser, obviously. There’s nothing inherent in that operation that poses significant problems, if the browser implementation is efficient.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned, I plan to support only modern browsers (with no IE11) - latest versions of Chrome, FF, Safari, Edge. So you're saying it's totally fine to do this? I tried testing this, and haven't really found problems indeed, but what if device has weak gpu

Comment: There’s no blanket answer here. Test it as much as possible, period.

Answer (score 1):

It obviously depends on the browser, and the computer. It should be able to upscale like that, but it would be very pixilated and ugly. I don’t know why you would want to do that. But yes, it should work.